# Adding Color Differentiation to Stacked Grouped Bar Chart in Plotly

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly, bar-chart

I have the following Pandas Data-Frame and want to create a Stacked Grouped bar chart with 'date' as the x-coordinate:

[image: Data-Frame]

I want the 'Power', 'RF' and 'Glob' columns to be stacked and differentiated by color

I have created the chart as follows:

```
fig = px.bar(month_df, x='date', y=['power', 'rf', 'glob'])

fig.show()
```

But it is not colored:
[image: result]

When I try to add a color parameter for these columns:

```
fig = px.bar(month_df, x='date', y=['power', 'rf', 'glob'], color=['power', 'rf', 'glob'])
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: All arguments should have the same length. The length of argument `color` is 3, whereas the length of  previously-processed arguments ['date', 'power', 'rf', 'glob'] is 11
```

How can I differentiate by these 3 columns only?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. When I run `fig = px.bar(month_df, x='date', y=['power', 'rf', 'glob'])`, I get stacked bars with different colors because this is the default behavior when you pass a list of columns to `y`. What happens if you run `fig = px.bar(month_df, x='date', y=['power', 'rf', 'glob'], template="plotly")`

Comment: Hi Derek - adding the template parameter has fixed the issue for me. Thank you!

Comment: oh great! i'm going to add my comment as an answer so anyone else who has the same problem as you can find the solution (people don't usually read comments)

Answer (score 0):

In plotly express, when you create bar chart by passing a list of columns to the y parameter, the default behavior should give you stacked bars with different colors.

For example, when I created a dataframe with your data and ran:

```
fig = px.bar(month_df, x='date', y=['power', 'rf', 'glob'])
```

I get the following:

[image]

Since the colors on your chart (including the background) are all black or white, you probably need to reset your template. You can do that with the following line:

```
fig = px.bar(month_df, x='date', y=['power', 'rf', 'glob'], template="plotly")
```